# Show user input and calculated input in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have no idea if this is possible or not. I dont think Ive seen it.

I have a table where i want users to input data. They may input any number from 0 to 10. I also want to show in this cell a bracketted number which is calculated form another table.

For example the user may type in 5 but when they leave the cell they would see

```
 5 (6)
```

where (6) is the calculated number. When they go to edit the cell they would see just the 5.

Not sure this is possible. If it isnt any other suggestions on how I can show this sort of thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly do this by horrifically misusing the conditional formatting system.

How many calculated values might you get? If the calculated value will always be between 0 and 10, like the input, you could set up 11 conditional formatting rules, one for each calculated value.

```
Formula | Custom number format
=B1=0   | 0" (0)"
=B1=1   | 0" (1)"
=B1=2   | 0" (2)" etc
```

There'd be a more elegant way using VBA, for sure.

Comment: oh that's so hacky and yet so beautifully simple. I'll go with that. Thanks!

Comment: The hacky hacks I've hacked in VBAless Excel these last two years… I've seen things you people would never believe.

Comment: Hi jack-deeth@ Do you know a way of converting this so it support one or two digit input. For example where the custom format could be: 0.5 (1.25)  Thanks!  jack-deeth

Answer (score 0):

I have used the ampersand for this:
="("&A1&")  "&"("&B1&")
where A1 and B1 contain the values...
I used it for displaying two averages in the same cell: class and cohort.